# How to calculate this ration integral

Tags: calculus

$\int \frac{x^3+2}{x^6+x^2+3}\cdot \frac{x^5}{\left(x^6-1\right)^2}dx
$
I have tried to factorize $x^6+x^2+3$ but got no solution .
I also tried to add something up and down but still no result can you give me some hint at least

Comment: I don't think it exists. Does the source question have limits, or are you trying to express this in closed form?

Comment: Wolfram says http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%5E3%2B2)%2F(x%5E6%2Bx%5E2%2B3) .

Comment: Are you sure that THAT is the integral you have to solve? It seems like a very weird one. Not easy to compute, despite it's possibile. I saw an edit, before, in which there was another part. Can you confirm that THAT is the integral?

Comment: $\int \:\frac{2+\sqrt{\frac{1+x}{x-1}}}{3+\sqrt[3]{\frac{1+x}{x-1}}+\frac{1+x}{x-1}}dx$ This is how i get there by replacing $\frac{1+x}{x-1}$ whit $t^6$ this is the given integral